# Webtorrent error Uncaught Error: Can only pipe to one destination

Tags: javascript, html, npm, webtorrent

I was expecting it to stream video from given torrent file and because it's provided as example on their official site, I expected it to work.

I tried creating default site (code provided here) to see if everything is set up correctly, but i got errors

```
Uncaught Error: Can only pipe to one destination
at ReadableState.pipe (webtorrent.min.js:16:173759)
at module.exports.pipe (webtorrent.min.js:16:179641)
at webtorrent.min.js:16:216698
at Array.forEach ()
at MP4Remuxer.seek (webtorrent.min.js:16:216602)
at VideoStream._pump (webtorrent.min.js:16:220728)
at VideoStream.VideoStream._onWaiting (webtorrent.min.js:16:219710)
```

.

```
webtorrent.min.js:16 GET https://webtorrent.io/torrents/Sintel/Sintel.mp4 net::ERR_CACHE_OPERATION_NOT_SUPPORTED
Client
```

and

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://tracker.fastcast.nz/' failed: webtorrent.min.js:16
```

I tried searching this question online but there sems to be no useful information.
Did I screw something up or is something wrong with webtorrent?

Basic info:
OS: Win11
Node.js: v18.16.0
npm: 9.5.1
webtorrent: 2.0.16

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hade the same issue. I solved it by switching to an older version. Try: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/webtorrent@1.8.0/webtorrent.min.js

I also created a small working demo app with nextjs, repo: https://github.com/Joel-Adving/web-torrent-streamer

Comment: It worked, thanks. Meanwhile, I gave up using webtorrent because it does not support udp trackers so I basically cannot stream any torrent from the pirate bay or 1337x or similar websites which makes it practically useless, is there a solution for that (that does not need server-side because I cannot host/pay to host anything)? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @IvanGolubić You could clone the repo i linked in the comment above, and then run it locally. No need to host it anywhere. It's using nextjs API endpoints. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have one more question, as I am designing my app to work on android and windows, can this be compiled for both (apk and exe) without needing user intervention post-install (like building and starting the build)?

Comment: You could use something like https://galaxies.dev/nextjs-and-capacitor to build and run it on android. It wraps the app in a native webview.